# Configuration Fast Search 2010

Tags: fast-search

i am trying to install **Sharepoint 2010 Fast Search** on a separate server.

***How i can communicate from Fast Search Server to Sharepoint server?***

How i can install fast search in a separate server which option i need to take(standalone or multiple server)?

Please provide any reference article for the above scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check these Steps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2010/04/09/installation-and-configuration-of-fast-search-server-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx